# ios: iTunes Connect Apps

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

I invited a developer to be part of my itunes connect. I also registered for the developer program (paid $99). The developer connects his device to xcode and requests a certificate but a pop up appears that says "To add this device, you need to add an Apple ID account that is enrolled in a Developer Program". How can my developer provision his iphone but not use my admin account. He is added on my itunes connect and his role is "technical" I am admin.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to the provisioning profiles, you will also have to invite your developer to the [iOS Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action). This will give him access to provisioning apps for his device.